# Laravel 5 multiple paginations on one page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to have 2 paginations on a single page.

View:

```
{{!! $items->appends(['page2' => Request::input('page2', 1)])->render() !!}}
```

But it is not working, as using custom $pageName for pagination ($items->setPageName('custom_page_parameter')) links are not working in laravel 5.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035006/laravel-5-pagination-wont-move-through-pages-with-custom-page-name

Here is how I did it in laravel 4:

[Laravel Multiple Pagination in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page)

What is Laravel 5 way of doing this?

Comment: This was answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page

Comment: @mahmoud That works in Laravel 4 but not in Laravel 5

Answer (score 11):

I've spent far too much time trying to find out how to do this, so thought I'd share my findings in case there is another poor soul like me out there. This works in 5.1...

In controller:

```
$newEvents = Events::where('event_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
    ->orderBy('event_date')
    ->paginate(15,['*'], 'newEvents');

$oldEvents = Events::where('event_date', '<', Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
    ->orderBy('event_date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15,['*'], 'oldEvents');
```

Then continue as usual in the view: `

```
// some code to display $newEvents
{!! $newEvents->render() !!}

// some code to display $oldEvents
{!! $oldEvents->render() !!}
```

Now, what this doesn't do is remember the page of $oldEvents when paging through $newEvents. Any idea on this?

References:

- [pull request addressing the original issue](http://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8475)
- [API docs for method](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate)

Comment: In short, ->paginate(15, ['*'], 'newEvents');
Do not forget the missing quote around 'newEvents'

Comment: In order to remember the page number for $oldEvents when paging $newEvents, use this:

{{ $newEvents -> appends(["oldEvents" => $oldEvents -> currentPage()]) -> links() }}

and vice versa for paging oldEvents:

{{ $oldEvents -> appends(["newEvents" => $newEvents -> currentPage()]) -> links() }}

Answer (score 7):

```
$published = Article::paginate(10, ['*'], 'pubArticles');
$unpublished = Article::paginate(10, ['*'], 'unpubArticles');
```

The third argument for paginate() method is used in the URI as follows:

> laravel/public/articles?pubArticles=3
>
> laravel/public/articles?unpubArticles=1

Answer (score 5):

In Controller:

```
$produk = Produk::paginate(5, ['*'], 'produk');
$region = Region::paginate(5, ['*'], 'region');
```

in view:

```
{{$produk->appends(['region' => $region->currentPage()])->links()}}    
{{$region->appends(['produk' => $produk->currentPage()])->links()}}
```

reference to :[[Laravel 5] Multi Paginate in Single Page](https://mosleim.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/laravel-5-multi-paginate-in-single-page/)

Comment: This is the better answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `\Paginator::setPageName('foo');` function befor buidling your paginator object:

```
    \Paginator::setPageName('foo');
    $models = Model::paginate(1);
    return view('view_foo', compact('models'));
```

This question might help too: [Laravel 5 pagination, won't move through pages with custom page name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035006/laravel-5-pagination-wont-move-through-pages-with-custom-page-name)

Also note there is a bug atm: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8000