# Laravel 5: Multiple Pagination in one page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am implementing multiple pagination in laravel 5. I know it could be achieved by using setPageName() as refer from [Laravel 5 pagination, won't move through pages with custom page name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035006/laravel-5-pagination-wont-move-through-pages-with-custom-page-name)

I know the issue already been resolved in 5.1. So I've updated my laravel by changing the laravel version in composer.json from "laravel/framework":5.0 to 5.1.10 and run composer update.

But the problem still exist. I can't set any page name for the page and the problem is exactly same in the link i've posted above. Only if i put the SetPageName('page') it will work perfectly.

Am I missing out something after I run the composer update ?

Answer (score 3):

[Laravel Multiple Pagination in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page/25553245#25553245)

I tried to make it work using the solution as mentioned in the above link, but it did not worked for me..

```
# use default 'page' for this
$data['test'] = $client->OpportunityList()->paginate(4);

# use custom 'opage' for this
$data['test'] = $client->OpportunityList()->paginate(4);
$data['test']->setPageName('opage');
```

These did not worked for me, so I passed the page name in the main paginate function - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L271

**Working Code**

```
$data['test'] = $client->OpportunityList()->paginate(4, ['*'], 'opage');
```

Works for simplePaginate as well - refer - 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L294

Comment: {!! $opage->render() !!} in view to render the newly named pagination

Answer (score 1):

The solution is passing a third argument to paginate() method:

```
$publishedArticles = Article::paginate(10, ['*'], 'published');
$unpublishedArticles = Article::paginate(10, ['*'], 'unpublished');
```

The URL:

> laravel/public/articles?published=3
>
> laravel/public/articles?unpublished=1